# How to exclude rows where matching join is in an SQL tree

Tags: sql, mysql, tree, join

**Update:** After playing around with this for a few hours, went with a multi-query solution and used a table that only contained parent attributes to determine which items needed updating.

---

Sorry for the poor title, I couldn't think how to concisely describe this problem.

I have a set of items that should have a 1-to-1 relationship with an attribute.

I have a query to return those rows where the data is wrong and this relationship has been broken (1-to-many). I'm gathering these rows to fix them and restore this 1-to-1  relationship.

This is a theoretical simplification of my actual problem but I'll post example table schema here as it was requested.

`item` table:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| item_id    | name       | attr_id   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 1          | BMW 320d   | 20        |
| 1          | BMW 320d   | 21        |
| 2          | BMW 335i   | 23        |
| 2          | BMW 335i   | 34        |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

`attribute` table:

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+
| attr_id | value           |  parent_id |
+---------+-----------------+------------+
|   20    | SE              |         21 | 
|   21    | M Sport         |          0 |
|   23    | AC              |         24 |
|   24    | Climate control |          0 |
              ....
|   34    | Leather seats   |          0 |
+---------+-----------------+------------+
```

A simple query to return items with more than one attribute.

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(attr_id)) AS attributes 
FROM item GROUP BY item_id HAVING attributes > 1
```

This gets me a result set like so:

```
+-----------+------------+
|   item_id | attributes |
+-----------+------------+
|    1      |          2 |
|    2      |          2 |
|    3      |          2 |
        -- etc. --
```

However, there's an exception. The `attribute` table can hold a tree structure, via parent links in the table. For certain rows, `parent_id` can hold the ID of another attribute. There's only one level to this tree. Example:

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+
| attr_id | value           |  parent_id |
+---------+-----------------+------------+
|   20    | SE              |         21 |
|   21    | M Sport         |          0 |
              ....
```

I **do not** want to retrieve items in my original query where, for a pair of associated attributes, they related like attributes 20 & 21.

I **do** want to retrieve items where:

- the attributes have no parent
- for two or more attributes they are not related (e.g. attributes 23 & 34)

Example result desired, just the item ID:

```
+------------+
| item_id    |
+------------+
| 2          |
+------------+
```

How can I join against `attributes` from `items` and exclude these rows?

Do I use a temporary table or can I achieve this from a single query?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add a sample data and structure for "items", and how it relates to "attributes" in all 3 scenarios: clean data (1-to-1), dirty (1-to-many), and the exception case?

Comment: These are all theoretical simplifications of the actual system. I'll add some examples when I get home.

Comment: Is there only 1 level to this tree, or n? If n, I think you need a recursive solution - which makes it harder.

Comment: Can you put the result requested as you put the other table ?

Comment: Yes, only 1 level to the tree. I've added an example desired result set. Question updated.

Comment: Is in the same tree your parent_id > attr_id (i.e. 21>20, 24 > 23) or can you have a tree like  10-->15-->5-->0 ? Can we assume that there is an order ?

Comment: the sequence of attribute IDs is not ordered, I just ordered it in my examples for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will extract only unique pairs of item and attribute (or its parent if any), thus eliminating the duplicates (this is per your request that an attribute can have only one parent, and the parent has no parents).

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.item_id AS iid, A.par_id AS aid
FROM 
    items AS I, 
    (SELECT AA.attr_id, IF(AA.parent_id = 0, AA.attr_id, AA.parent_id) AS par_id 
     FROM attribute AS AA) AS A
WHERE I.attr_id = A.attr_id
ORDER BY I.item_id
```

So, using the above query as a subtable for your counting query will work (same approach I used with the A subtable above):

```
SELECT SUB.iid, COUNT(DISTINCT(SUB.aid)) AS attributes
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT I.item_id AS iid, A.par_id AS aid
     FROM 
        items AS I, 
        (SELECT AA.attr_id, IF(AA.parent_id = 0, AA.attr_id, AA.parent_id) AS par_id 
         FROM attribute AS AA) AS A
     WHERE I.attr_id = A.attr_id
     ORDER BY I.item_id) AS SUB
GROUP BY SUB.iid
HAVING attributes > 1
```

I have added 3 more rows to your example items table, to accommodate the case, where an item can be linked only to an attribute with parent, but not the parent itself (i.e. item 3 -> 23 and 3 -> 20), and 4 -> 23.

Running the above query lists only items 2 and 3 with 2 attributes each.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a single query:

```
SELECT
    i.item_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(i.attr_id)) AS attributes 
FROM
    items i
INNER JOIN
    attributes a
        ON i.attr_id = a.attr_id
WHERE
    a.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY
    i.item_id
HAVING
    i.labels > 1
```

Comment: I thought I could do that too but ... that excludes rows where 1 of the related attributes has a parent but ... the parent is not in the set of associated attributes for the given item. The data isn't that clean at present.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems it 's not possible with one query since we have nothing to group by, or nothing to sort on. 
The one thing left will be to do some recursive call but since there are no recursive SQL in mysql or if your attribute data have a rule where for all linked attribute attr_id < parent_id.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this, I updated all rows in `item` with the parent attribute ID, where one is  available.

So in my example `item` table, with the attribute IDs updated it looks like:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| item_id    | name       | attr_id   |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 1          | BMW 320d   | 21        |
| 1          | BMW 320d   | 21        |
| 2          | BMW 335i   | 23        |
| 2          | BMW 335i   | 34        |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

First I got a list of attribute relations (child-to-parent):

```
SELECT a.attr_id, a.parent_id FROM item i JOIN attribute a 
USING (attr_id) WHERE parent_id > 0 GROUP BY a.attr_id
```

I looped around this in code and updated the rows in `item` that referenced a child attribute.

```
$update = array();

foreach ($relations as $child => $parent) {
    if (!isset($update[$parent]))
        $update[$parent] = array();

    $update[$parent][] = $child;
}
```

Loop around `$update` to update `item`. With this done I was able to use my original query:

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(attr_id)) AS attributes 
FROM item GROUP BY item_id HAVING attributes > 1
```

I couldn't get one query to work.

Comment: I just edited my answer and did it with one (complicated :) ) query. Check it out :)